# Template parameter based on expected return type

Tags: c++

Right now I have something like this:

```
int a = getVal<int>("key1");
double b = getVal<double>("key2");
```

where getVal() just casts and returns the value corresponding to the key. Is it possible to turn that into this:

```
int a = getVal("key1");
double b = getVal("key2");
```

It's not a huge difference in code, but I'm mostly just wondering if this is possible. Thanks for the help.

Comment: `getVal("key1", a);` would be about the closest you can get.

Comment: if it would be Java, then you could use something like `Integer a = getVal<>("key1");`. In C++ right hand side expression determines the overral type, so you have to specify it explicitly (e.g. via a fake extra parameter as @chris suggests).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this:

```
template <typename T>
T getVal(const string& key);  // as before

class ValProxy {
private:
  ValProxy(const string& key) : key_(key) {}
  string key_;

  friend ValProxy getVal(const string& key);
public:
  template <typename T>
  operator T() const {
    return getVal<T>(key_);
  }
};

ValProxy getVal(const string& key) {
  return ValProxy(key);
}
```

Comment: Looks like that would work. Also taught me something about assignment and using cast operators. Thanks!